# Unneeded column added trying to set up OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to set up a OneToMany relationship between an author and his posts with author as the foreign key and username as primary key, using Java EE 6 and toplink+eclipselink as persistence provider.

Here is what i have:

Annotations in class User

```
@Id
@NotNull(message = "Please enter username")
@Size(min = 8, max = 40)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false) 
private String username;

...

private Collection<BlogEntry> blg = new ArrayList<BlogEntry>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="user")
    public Collection<BlogEntry> getBlg() {
        return blg;
    }
```

Annotations in class BlogEntry

```
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 40)
    private String author;

... 

private User user;

    @ManyToOne()
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
```

The problem is that a new column(USER_USERNAME) is added when inserting values into BlogEntry Table, which of course shows an error of the field not existing in BlogEntry:

```
INSERT INTO BLOGENTRY (ID, CONTENT, AUTHOR, TITLE, CREATED, USER_USERNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [301, xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx, 2011-06-07 12:49:07.014, null]
```

I would be very glad to learn why such a column is added or what to fix to get a simple OneToMany relationship using username and author fields. I searched and tried many tutorials but seems i'm missing something.

Comment: I didn't find the unneeded column mentioned in the question. Are you referring to the AUTHOR and USER_USERNAME columns? If so, which one is unneeded?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an existing `AUTHOR` column as a foreign key, you need to map many-to-one relationship to that column as follows:

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = 'author')
private User user;
```

Note that in typical case you can remove a separate `author` field from the class, since now it can be obtained as `user.getUsername()`. If you need both fields in the class, you need to mark one of them as read-only with `insertable = false, updateable = false`, because only one read-write field can be mapped to a particular column.

Comment: Damn, I was about to write that!

Comment: I did what you said and got this error: Column name 'AUTHOR' appears more than once times in the column list of an INSERT statement.

Comment: @Demonikc: What exactly did you do: removed `author` field or marked it read-only?

Comment: I added @Column(insertable = false, updateable = false) before the existing author field and no related errors are shown anymore. Just a question: what could be a good way to test that the relationship works?

Comment: @Demonick, using JPA, issue INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE actions from both ends of the relation, if you want to test it comprehensively. Inserting, updating and deleting from the owner should result in compensating actions on the other side of the relationship, but not vice-versa.

Comment: Still seems not to work, while deleting i got this error: DELETE FROM USER_BLOGENTRY WHERE EXISTS(SELECT USERNAME FROM USER WHERE (USERNAME LIKE ?) AND USERNAME = USER_BLOGENTRY.User_USERNAME), it doesn't recognize 'USER_BLOGENTRY.USER_USERNAME'